# ggplot issue when using facets, geom_vline, with NAs

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I run the code below, I get the error further below.

```
library(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(id=rep(c(1,2),each=3),x=c(1:3,1:3),y=2:7,z=as.numeric(rep(NA,6)))
g = ggplot(d,aes(x,y))
g = g + geom_point() + geom_line()
g = g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=z))
g = g + facet_wrap(~id)
print(g)
```

ERROR:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
Removed 6 rows containing missing values (geom_vline).
```

I understand the code above is a bit silly, but it should work.  In practice, usually I have numeric values for some numbers in z and NAs for others, but when I take subsets of my data, sometimes I have all NAs and this then causes the error above.  When I was using the older version of ggplot2 I did not have this problem.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Can't reproduce with R version 3.2.3 and ggplot2 2.1.0

Comment: You may want to post the version of `ggplot2` you are using.

Comment: Thank you.  I was using ggplot2 2.0.0.  I've since updated to ggplot2 2.1.0 and it fixed the problem (which for me required R 3.2.4) and it works

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your line:

```
g = g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=z))
```

Because z is NA in each case, this generates an error. You don't get this error if at least one of the values is a real number. Remove this and the rest works fine.

As you said in your question, you want code that will always work whether or not the values are all NA. You can achieve this by replacing:

```
g = g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=z))
```

with an if statement:

```
if (!all(is.na(z))) g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=z))
```

Now, if your z column is all NAs, the code will ignore the `geom_vline` call.

```
z <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
d = data.frame(id=rep(c(1,2),each=3),x=c(1:3,1:3),y=2:7,z=as.numeric(z))
g = ggplot(d,aes(x,y))
if (!all(is.na(z))) g <- g + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=z))
g = g + geom_point() + geom_line()
g = g + facet_wrap(~id)
print(g)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updating to ggplot2 2.1.0 (and R 3.2.4) resolved the issue.